# Селект в коллекцию с пользовательским типом данных

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как сделать селект в в коллекцию с пользовательским типом данных?

Например, есть таблица:

```
create table emp (  
  empno    number(4,0),  
  ename    varchar2(10),  
  job      varchar2(9),  
  mgr      number(4,0),  
  hiredate date,  
  sal      number(7,2),  
  comm     number(7,2),  
  deptno   number(2,0),  
  constraint pk_emp primary key (empno),  
  constraint fk_deptno foreign key (deptno) references dept (deptno)  
)
```

Cоздаю пользовательский тип:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE typ_emp as OBJECT (
  name VARCHAR2(20),
  deptno VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_tbl AS TABLE OF typ_emp;
```

Пишу функцию:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getEmpl
  RETURN emp_tbl
  AS
  tbl emp_tbl ;
  BEGIN
    SELECT e.ENAME, e.DEPTNO INTO tbl FROM EMP e;
  RETURN tbl;
  END;
```

Компиляция с ошибками:

> PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Ну Вы выбираете два значения, а пытаетесь присвоить их в одно, пусть и с двумя компонентами. Попробуйте что-нибудь вроде `SELECT e.ENAME, e.DEPTNO INTO tbl.name, tbl.deptno FROM EMP e;`

Comment: @akina так оно не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо обернуть результат запроса в нужный тип и извлекать через `bulk collect into`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getEmpl
  RETURN emp_tbl
  AS
  tbl emp_tbl ;
  BEGIN
    SELECT typ_emp(e.ENAME, e.DEPTNO)
    BULK   COLLECT INTO tbl 
    FROM   EMP e;
  END;
```

Чуть больше примеров на [en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305161/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-select-into-table-of-object-type).

И сейчас ваша функция не возвращает никакого результат, это странно.

Comment: Пардон, забыл return в этом примере поставить. На самом деле у меня другая функция, но смысл смысл такой же ( надо результат селекта присвоить типу.

Answer (score 4):

Вот так можно вернуть через `INTO` результат объектного представления:

```
create or replace function getEmpl return emp_tbl as
    ret emp_tbl;
begin
    select cast (multiset (select e.name, e.deptno from emp e) as emp_tbl) 
    into ret
    from dual;

    return ret;
end;
/
```

---

Следует учесть

Не рекомендуется для очень больших коллекций, так как создаются временные объекты в SQL контехте, поэтому уступит по быстродействию `bulk collect`. И кроме того, `fetch ... limit <rows>`, если потребуется, в данном случае недоступен.